# ВКонтакте SDK авторизация

Tags: ios, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте, возникла такая странная проблемка.
Использую для авторизации VKSDK для Android и для iOS
После успешной авторизации шлю на сервер token (чтобы не светить реальный userId) и дальше сервер по этому токену получает информацию по пользователю.

И вот дальше вот какая проблема токен полученный от Андроида на 1 символ больше, НО работают оба токена.

А проблема возникает из-за количества запросов с сервера.
Если авторизация была через андроид то все хорошо.
Если же iOS то временами вылетает ошибка что нужен ввод капчи.

Кто сталкивался? VKSDK для Android не давно обновил на новую версию. Также сделал с iOS.
Но проблема осталась.

Comment: так а с чем проблема? iOS, или Android?

Comment: Если же iOS  то временами вылетает ошибка что нужен ввод капчи. - эм ну как бы с iOS

Comment: Запрос капчи там стандартное, документированное поведение. Серверы vkontakte сами решают, когда нужна капча, а когда нет, логика их работы закрыта. Вы ходитет обойти запрос капчи?